# How to convert encrypted outlook msg file to smime.p7m in c# and vice versa?

Tags: encryption, outlook, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook to process a pst file. But there are some encrypted emails because of which I am not being able to open it. 
  I am using EWS for synching exchange emails and I noticed that encrypted emails are shown as smime.p7m attachments.
So I was wondering how OWA gets smime.p7m format for the msg file??
And also is there a way to convert smime.p7m file to outook msg file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook Object Model always represents signed/encrypted messages as regular IPM.Note MailItem objects.

To get to the underlying p7m attachment, you can either use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language - I am its author) - it exposes the [RDOEncryptedMessage](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdoencryptedmessage.htm) object.

Comment: Thanks Dimitry!!! , Btw what is the way to differentiate signed only , encrypted only, and signed + encrypted msg in redemption??

Comment: There is no difference in Redemption - in both cases the data is stored in a p7m attachment.